# how to print at the start of each line printed to the console, print the line number of the file

Tags: c

my out put should be this

1) Hello...
2) Programming 1...
3) Students!
4) Welcome to File I/O!

I have done everything except i cannot figure out how to print the numbers for each line??

so far i got

```
#include <stido.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{

    char string[200];
    FILE* file = fopen("file2.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(file, "%c", string) ==1)
    {
        printf("%c", *string);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you would want to create a temp variable. Increment the temp variable during each loop of your while loop.  int lineNum = 1;   while...( sprintf(str, "%d", linNum); printf("%c", *string );}  something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 1;
char line[200];
FILE* file = fopen("file2.txt","r");
while(fgets(line, 200, file))
{
    printf("%d) %s", num, line);
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid limitation of line length like `char string[200]`, simple detect the start of a line by checking if the precious `char` was a line-feed and then print the number.  No need to be conservative on line count, so use a wide type.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stido.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    int previous = '\n';  
    int ch;
    unsigned long long line_count = 0;
    FILE* file = fopen("file2.txt","r");
    assert(file);
    while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
      if (previous == '\n') {
        printf("%llu) ", ++line_count);
      }
      fputc(ch, stdout);
      previous = ch;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```